Oracle 19c зависает на разных этапах установки
Пытаюсь установить Oracle 19c, если запускаю только setup.exe , то установщик виснет на этапе выбора типа установки:
C:\client32\install>setup.exe


Если же запускаю установщик так:
setup.exe -ignorePrereq -J"-Doracle.install.client.validate.clientSupportedOSCheck=false"

То установка зависает на Step 4 "Perform Prerequisite Checks"

Попробуйте запустить установщик от имени Администратора

Конечно же всё через админа, с отключенным антивирусом.Кстати, если ставить 12с, то устанавливается без проблем
